# Show that $\int_{X}u\, \mathrm{d}\mu\leq 4$ and $\int_{X}u\, \mathrm{d}\mu=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measureable space. Let $u\in \mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{R}}^{+}(\mathcal{A})$ and $\lbrace u_{j}\rbrace_{j\geq 1}$ be a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{R}}^{+}(\mathcal{A})$ that satisfies $u_{j}\to u$ and $\lim_{j\to\infty}\int_{X}u_{j}\, \mathrm{d}\mu=4$. Note that the convergence is pointwise convergence i.e. $\forall x\in X:u_{j}(x)\to u(x)$.

How do I show that $\int_{X}u\, \mathrm{d}\mu\leq 4$? All I know is

$$\int_{X}u\, \mathrm{d}\mu=\lim_{j\to\infty}\int_{X}u_{j}\, \mathrm{d}\mu=\sup_{j\in \mathbb{N}}\int_{X}u_{j}\, \mathrm{d}\mu$$

I want to give an example that the abovementioned condition is satisfied and where $\int_{X}u\, \mathrm{d}\mu=1$.

Comment: It is important to explain what do you mean by $u_j\to u$. What kind of convergence do you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The convergence is pointwise convergence i.e. $\forall x\in X:u_{j}(x)\to u(x)$. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conseqeunce of [Fatou's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma):

$$
\int_X \liminf_{n\to\infty}u_n\,d\mu\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_X u_n\,d\mu,
$$
and hence
$$
\int_X u\,d\mu=\int_X \liminf_{n\to\infty}u_n\,d\mu\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_X u_n\,d\mu=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X u_n\,d\mu=4.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me with the rest of the problem in OP?